# Formatting Header to Append to Data Frame in R

Tags: r, dataframe, import, import-from-excel, read.csv

I'm attempting to create a specifically formatted header to append to a data frame I have created in `R`.

The essence of my problem is that it seems increasingly difficult (maybe impossible?) to create a header that breaks away from a typical one row by one column framework, without merging the underlying table, using the `dataframe` concept in `R`.

The issue stems from me not being able to figure out a way to import this particular format of a header into `R` through methods such as `read.csv` or `read.xlsx` which preserve the format of the header.

Reading in a header of this format into `R` from a `.csv` or `.xlsx` is quite ugly and doesn't preserve the original format. The format of the header I'm trying to create and append to an already existing dataframe I have of 17 nameless columns in `R` could be represented in such a way:

[image]

Where the number series of 1 - 17 represents the already existing data frame of 17 nameless columns of data that I have created in `R` in which I wish to append to this header. Could anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: It is not clear if you're still trying to properly _import_ your excel file, or if you've given up this battle, and you're now just trying to _export_ the result of your processing to this format (as an xlsx file too, I guess) ? Or both? If it's the latter, could you provide a sample of your data?

Comment: You are attempting to merge cells, strictly an Excel method. Hence, you need to access its object library. R only dumps data files in flat files of two-dimensions with a value in each cell with no formatting.

Answer (score 0):

You are correct that this header will not work *within* R.  The data frame only supports single header values and wont do something akin to a merged cell in excel.

However if you simply want to export your data to an .csv or .xlsx (use write.csv) then just copy your header in, that could work.

OR

You could add in a factor column to your data frame to capture the information contained in the top level of your header.